# numpy: unexpected result when dividing a vertical array by one of its own elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So, I created an vertical numpy array, used the /= operator and the output seems to be incorrect. 
Basically if x is a vector, s a scalar. I would expect x /= s have every entry of x divided by s. However, I couldn't make much sense of the output. The operator is only applied on part of the entries in x, and I am not sure how they are chosen.

```
In [8]: np.__version__
Out[8]: '1.10.4'

In [9]: x = np.random.rand(5,1)

In [10]: x
Out[10]:
array([[ 0.47577008],
       [ 0.66127875],
       [ 0.49337183],
       [ 0.47195985],
       [ 0.82384023]])   ####

In [11]: x /= x[2]

In [12]: x
Out[12]:
array([[ 0.96432356],
       [ 1.3403253 ],
       [ 1.        ],
       [ 0.95660073],
       [ 0.82384023]])   #### this entry is not changed.
```

Comment: This is also the case (for me) in version 
1.10.1

Comment: I also see the surprising behavior.  I suspect it's something to do with using the array on the right-hand side at the same time you are modifying it on the left-hand side.  If you assign `y = x[2]; x /= y`, it does what you expect.

Comment: `x[2]` is not a scalar. It is a 1D array of length 1 (because `x` is a two-dimensional 5x1 array), and this causes a problem because it changes during the operation. If you used an actual scalar such as `x[2][0]` it would work correctly.

Comment: Can only reproduce this on my linux machines and not my windows box.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I cannot reproduce that. The error still occurs.

Comment: Very odd bug. Appears to only occur when the length of the first dimension is odd eg. `(5,1),  (7, 1), ...`

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I had made a 10-element array to test with.  Looks like the even/odd length is clearly a factor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your value of x[2] changes to 1 midway through the evaluation. you need to make a copy of the value then divide each element by it, either assign it to another variable or use copy i.e.

```
from copy import copy
x /= copy(x[2])
```

To understand why we need to do this lets look under the hood of what is happening.

```
In [9]: x = np.random.rand(5,1)
```

Here we define x as an array, but what isn't exactly clear that each element in this array is technically an array also. This is the important distinction, as we are not dealing with defined values rather numpy array objects so in the next line:

```
In [11]: x /= x[2]
```

We end up essentially 'looking up' the value in x[2] which returns an array with one value, but because we're looking this up each time it is possible to change.

A cleaner solution would be to flatten the array into 1d therefore x[2] with now equal 0.49337183 instead of array( [0.49337183])

So before we do `x /= x[2]` we can call `x = x.flatten()`

Or better yet keep it 1d from the start `x = np.random.rand(5)`

And as for the reason x[3] changes and x[4] does not, the only real helpful answer I can give is that the division does not happen in order, complex buffering timey wimey stuff.

Comment: How does this explain the correct answer of `0.9566...`?

Comment: That could be true, but that doesn't explain why the 4th element is changed, since then `x[2]==1`.

Comment: I am not an expert in numpy but many datasets in python are not stored in order, is possible that behind the scenes they are evaluated in a different order? try different lengths of data? see what happens?

Comment: It is using some sort of buffering; so operations like this are unpredictable.  Use this `copy` or ` numpy.ufunc.at

`.

Comment: Instead of flattening, just make it a 1D array to start with: `np.random.rand(5)`.

Comment: Another cause could be use of SSE2 instructions --- I'd expect buffering to result to more entries than just 4 being correct. However, as it stands, currently such operations with inputs overlapping with output and nontrivial data dependence are undefined in Numpy. They may become defined sometime in the future, but this will take a nontrivial amount of work (already the problem of deciding whether two strided arrays overlap has exponential runtime in the number of dimensions).

Comment: good points all round. @pv if we look at it the other way only 1 answer is incorrect, extend the array to a larger dataset and you will see most of the answers are correct. 4 out of 5 is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

It is only for odd size of vector in theory but if you do :
`x = np.random.rand(5,1)
a = x[2]*1
x/=a`

it will be working